# Help identify smd component

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount, zener

Im trying to repair a diagnostic interface, I've got a burnt chip and cant find any board data.

Multimeter: diode mode in one direction reading : 1380, in other way 820
test in resistance ( 2000 ohm setting) I get 1510; in other 1430 in other direction.

[image]

[image]
In need of identifying silver/Gray SMD part with writing on it "24"

No luck finding it.

Answer (score 3):

Probably a Vishay [Si9241A](https://www.vishay.com/docs/70787/si9241.pdf) or compatible bus transceiver. An exposed part that could be subject to damage.

The other part may be a [3.6V zener](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PDZ-B_SER.pdf) part number PDZ3.6B. Part marking appears to be Z4. It might be intended to produce ~3.3V from 5V with ~2mA zener current.

Comment: Not that component, the component that looks like a diode, in gray/ silver color that has writing |24^ on it. and it's inline with 681

Comment: Honestly, simply genius, I would have never thought it was Z instead of 2.  This is very useful. Thank you very much!